# Objective C Finding value of HTTPBody

Tags: ios, objective-c, api

Xcode 5, I'm debugging and trying to see the value of the HTTPBody that's being POSTed to an API. The API isn't registering the POST so I need to debug and see if the content of it is correct.

Here's the line of code:

```
request.HTTPBody = [report multiPartFormDataWithBoundary:boundary];
```

Debugging into the multiPartFormDataWithBoundary method I can see the form POST elements being built up but when it comes out of that method and is assigned as above I can no longer see the contents in the debugger.

How can I check what is being sent to the API?

Comment: It would be easy if you have access to the server. Or else use some http request proxy like charles to see what the request is actually carrying.

Comment: Hadn't considering Charles, I think I have a version of it here.

Comment: You should probably give it a try.

Comment: That I shall, thank you for the suggestion. If anyone else knows how I can find the answer through debugging in Xcode feel free to suggest.

Comment: `po [[NSString alloc] initWithData:request.HTTPBody encoding:4]`

Answer (score 0):

Since HTTPBody is a NSData type, you can convert to a NSString and show it by NSLog.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:request.HTTPBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Comment: Tried that and it said there was an error. I don't have the exact error in front of me at the moment but I believe it was an unexpected error, the scariest kind I always think.

Comment: hi, why are you using UTF8? how are you sure that this is the HTTPBody's encoding?